# java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to run my spring boot project jar on commandline by below command

**D:\Installation\jdk-17.0.1_windows-x64_bin\jdk-17.0.1\bin\java -jar MyApp.jar**

but i will get below error:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[/MyApp]]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:923) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:886) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1383) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:252) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:430) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:926) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:485) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:123) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar!/:3.0.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar!/:3.0.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:486) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar!/:3.0.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:210) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar!/:3.0.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:183) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar!/:3.0.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:161) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar!/:3.0.2]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:578) ~[spring-context-6.0.4.jar!/:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar!/:3.0.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar!/:3.0.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:432) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar!/:3.0.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar!/:3.0.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar!/:3.0.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar!/:3.0.2]
        at com.codemaster.app.MyAppApplication.main(MyAppApplication.java:18) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[MyApp.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:95) ~[MyApp.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[MyApp.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65) ~[MyApp.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[/MyApp]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1383) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
        ... 37 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: zip file closed
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.ensureOpen(ZipFile.java:831) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.getManifestName(ZipFile.java:1057) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$1.getManifestName(ZipFile.java:1100) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.getManEntry(JarFile.java:937) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.checkForSpecialAttributes(JarFile.java:1000) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.isMultiRelease(JarFile.java:389) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFileUrlJar.<init>(JarFileUrlJar.java:68) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFactory.newInstance(JarFactory.java:41) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.process(StandardJarScanner.java:393) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs(StandardJarScanner.java:328) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.doScanClassPath(StandardJarScanner.java:271) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:234) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars(TldScanner.java:262) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-11.0.0-M1.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scan(TldScanner.java:104) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-11.0.0-M1.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer.onStartup(JasperInitializer.java:83) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-11.0.0-M1.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5144) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
        ... 43 common frames omitted
```

My pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.cornerstone</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyApp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>MyApp</name>
    <description>Spring Boot Project for MyApp</description>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.vaadin.external.google</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-json</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>11.0.0-M1</version> -->
            <version>10.1.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20220924</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.14</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>MyApp</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I am struggling from 3 days but not get any solution for the above issue.
Is anybody know why I am getting this error